# Definition of Iterated (Double Integral)

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definition, riemann-integration

A double integral, in Calculus III is done using Reimann Sums, dividing the area into rectangles.

Thomas's Calculus says that the norm of the partition is the largest width or height of any rectangle in the partition.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXh9AQkKmsw&list=PLHXZ9OQGMqxc_CvEy7xBKRQr6I214QJcd&index=25&t=4s), at around minute 6.40 tells met the norm of the partition is the largest area.

Does area work in this context? Since I can then make narrow, long rectangles to get values that are different from the actual volumes.

Comment: Just shows you shouldn't trust every math video. Moreover, the guy doesn't pronounce "analogous" correctly.

Comment: To be fair, the explanation is quite good. It covers the concept well. Most calc iii courses will not get into the definition (unless they are honours)

Comment: If you're looking for a more rigorous treatment of multivariable calculus (including linear algebra), you might enjoy some of my 112 lectures on YouTube, linked in my profile.

Comment: Will definitely have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual definition of the *norm* or *mesh* of a partition of a region in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is that it is the maximum dimension of any rectangle in the partition.  This essentially comes down to the fact that you can control the size of a function "near" a point (via, e.g., continuity), but you can't necessarily control the size of a function far aways—hence there is a need to keep points in any part of a partition "close" to each other.

Note that if you relax this requirement, and only look at the area, bad things can happen.  For example, consider a function $f : [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $y=0$, and} \\
0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}$$

Consider a partition by intervals of the form $[x_j,x_j+\varepsilon]\times[0,1]$.  The upper Riemann sum on such a partition will always be $1$, while the lower Riemann sum will always be $0$.  As this disagree, we might conclude that the function is not integrable, which is a problem.

I will note that the example I gave is not continuous, but a similar continuous example can be obtained by considering a function like

$$ g : [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{R} : (x,y) \mapsto y. $$